# Pandas: substring search and replace column headers using a RegEx pattern in replace()

Tags: regex, pandas

I have the following Pandas dataframes:

```
foo = {
    "country" : ["United States", "Canada", "Japan", "Australia"],
    "code" : [7, 2, 1, 4]
}

bar = {
    "country_code" : ["France", "Germany", "Mexico"],
    "code" : [3, 6, 8]
}

baz = {
    "country_code" : ["China", "Thailand", "Israel"],
    "code" : [9, 10, 11]
}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(foo)
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(bar)
df_3 = pd.DataFrame(baz)

df_1
    country         code
0   United States   7
1   Canada          2
2   Japan           1
3   Australia       4

df_2
    country_code    code
0   France          3
1   Germany         6
2   Mexico          8

df_3
    country_id          code
0   China               9
1   Thailand            10
2   Israel              11
```

If a column header contains the substring `country`, I would like to be able to replace the column name as simply `country`.  For example, "country_code" would be replaced "country" and "country_id" would be replaced with "country".

I can do this easily enough with the following:

```
df_2.rename(columns={'country_code' : 'country'}, inplace=True)
df_3.rename(columns={'country_id' : 'country'}, inplace=True)
```

Or, as follows:

```
col_dict = {'country_code': 'country', 'country_id': 'country'}
df_2.columns = [col_dict.get(x, x) for x in df_2.columns]
df_3.columns = [col_dict.get(x, x) for x in df_3.columns]
```

These approaches work, but they presume that I know the column names beforehand (which I may not).

I tried using RegEx in the `.replace()` method:

```
df_3.rename(columns={col: col.replace('[(?i)country]', 'country') for col in df_3.columns}, inplace=True)
```

But, this failed with this error message:

```
TypeError: str.replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

Is it even possible to use RegEx in this way?  Or, is there a more elegant approach?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

The following approach works and is more robust than previous attempts:

```
for elem in df_3.columns:
    if 'country' in elem:
        df_3.rename(columns={elem : 'country'}, inplace=True
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop/list comprehension with f string would do. Lets try

```
df_list = [df_1,df_2,df_3]#Create list of df

for df in df_list:
    #Loop through the list selecting columns that contain country and listing them
    cols =list(df.filter(regex='country',axis=1).columns)
    #Loop through list of columns names
    for i in cols:
        # Rename columns in place
        df.rename(columns={fr"{i}":"country"}, inplace=True)
```